# connecting mysql using sqlalchemy & Docker compose

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I tried to make mysql connect with docker below is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:

#    build: ./mysql
    image: mysql:8
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: finops
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Roh1t#mishra
      # MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'Roh1t#mishra'
      # MYSQL_TCP_PORT: '3306'

    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    expose:
      - 3307
  api:
    build: ./cost-controller-engine
    ports:
      - 8023:8023
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: db:3307
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    expose:
      - 8023

  # Names our volume
```

and here is my code to create engine using sqlalchemy:-

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:Roh1t#mishra@127.0.0.1:3306/finops", echo=True)
```

but getting error like

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

Help me to connect MySQL using sqlalchemy & docker.

Answer (score 1):

The default database port is 3306, by commenting the env line it still remains 3306 (uncommenting it and setting a different value will change the port).

If you don't need to connect to the database externally (outside of the containers) then there is no need for `expose`/`ports`, which is currently set to port `3307` and therefore not used.

*Note: the `ports` setting also acts as an expose*

If we use docker compose and therefore its easy to connect multiple containers, we use the container names for their network calls, in this case if from the container `api` I want to connect to the database in the container `db` I use `db:3306`, in your code it is called `127.0.0.1` which is localhost and it always calls only itself. So if I call `127.0.0.1` from the `api` container I call `api`.

Try modifying it to:

`create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:Roh1t#mishra@db:3306/finops")`

**Update:**

Remove `db.hostname: localhost` in docker-compose.

I am attaching sample test files when I successfully connect to the database.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from time import sleep


engine = create_engine("mysql://root:toor@db:3306/my_db")
con = engine.connect()

con.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl (id INT, flag INT);")

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect(only=['tbl'])

print(metadata.tables)
```

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
    - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
```

Output from `docker-compose logs`:

```
api_1  | FacadeDict({'tbl': Table('tbl', MetaData(bind=Engine(mysql://root:***@db:3306/my_db)), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<tbl>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('key', VARCHAR(length=20), table=<tbl>), Column('val', VARCHAR(length=20), table=<tbl>), schema=None)})
```

Comment: it says  sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 
'db' (-3)

Comment: This is because of the `hostname: localhost` in the database definition. Try removing it.

I am attaching samples of docker-compose and test code to this post. It's purely a sample and dummy code just to test the DB and connect to it.

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-3)    

same thing I am getting after removing localhost as well.